# How to integrate in DataStax opscenter a ssl intermediate certificate?

Tags: ssl, certificate, opscenter

All the informations I found show only how to activate SSL key + SSL cert, like [this one](http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.1/opsc/configure/opscConfiguringEnablingHttps_t.html).

```
#ssl_keyfile = /var/lib/opscenter/ssl/opscenter.key
#ssl_certfile = /var/lib/opscenter/ssl/opscenter.pem
#ssl_port = 8443
```

But not how has the SSL intermediate to be integrated?

- There seems no `ssl_intermediate` file option.
- Appending intermediate cert to the certfile is not recognized by opscenter
  webserver.

Answer (score 0):

OpsCenter developer here. This post is pretty old but it recently came across my radar, answering for posterity...

The PEM format allows multiple certificates to be concatenated together. For certs with a trust chain, add the whole chain into a single PEM file and point ssl_certfile at it. Digitcert has a nice simple document detailing certificate concatenation in PEM files: https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pem-ssl-creation.htm

Edit: Just saw that you mentioned that appending didn't work, hard to say what's going on but if you append the full trust chain (not just the nearest intermediate) appending should work as expected.